# CSS класс в зависимости от размера изображения (DJANGO)

Tags: python, html, css, django

Есть модель джанго с полем для загрузки изображения, которое потом отображается на странице. Так вот, мне нужно к каждой модели повесить определенный флаг размера картинки, в зависимости от которого кидать её в дивы с разными классами. Я сделал такой вариант: накидал функцию, показанную ниже, и пользуюсь им в контроллере, закидывая результат функции в контекст при рендере. Всё работает, однако вариант мне этот не нравится, слишком много с ним проблем, да и с архитектурной точки зрения не оптимально, так как приходится вставлять блок с проверкой в каждом контроллере. Как можно ещё решить данную задачу? Может можно определять это напрямую через css?

функция:

```
def image_flag_foo(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    (width, height) = im.size
    if width > height:
        x = width/height*100
        if x > 125:
            return 'width'
        else:
            return 'normal'
    else:
        x = height/width*100
        if x > 125:
            return 'height'
        else:
            return 'normal'
```

views:

```
if brick.image:
    image_flag = image_flag_foo(brick.image)
else:
    image_flag = 'no_image'
context = {
   'brick': brick,
   'image_flag' : image_flag,
```

template:

```
{% if image_flag == 'width' %}
  <img class="card-photo-width" src="{{brick.image.url}}" alt="">
{% endif %}
{% if image_flag == 'height' %}
  <img class="card-photo-height" src="{{brick.image.url}}" alt="">
{% endif %}
{% if image_flag == 'normal' %}
  <img class="card-photo-normal" src="{{brick.image.url}}" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал функцию кастомным тегом, узнал что у `image` есть встроенные параметры `width` и `height`, так что вместо библиотеки `pillow` передаю теперь их напрямую. И в шаблоне перед тем, что указано в вопросе поставил вот такую конструкцию:

```
  {% if brick.image %}
  {% image_flag_foo brick.image.width brick.image.height as image_flag %}
  {% endif %}
```